# Jboss eap with Apache web server

Tags: apache, jboss

I am using an Apache web Server before jboss eap which has one ear deployed. Before the Webserver, there is a load balancer installed. So as I recognized when having multiple requests at the same time, the response time sucks. Thats why i am thinking of second Apache Webserver with same resources as the first one. So does the second webserver helping to fit better multiple requests at same time when using the same jboss eap?

Comment: Check each component one by one to figure out which one is the cause, then you fix that.  Adding a second Apache will not help if JBoss is the cause.  It could even make it worst by over flooding the server.

Comment: Hmm problem was definetely JBoss. So how can I handle this issue. I walk away that normally one webserver should be enough. Is it possible to add a second jboss eap? In this case, how will be the deployment of the ear, meaning is it possible to deploy once on both? The other question will be, how the Apache web Server orchestring these two jboss?

Comment: Options are: **1** check if it is the JVM or the server that creates the bottle neck.  JVM can be tuned or increased, server made bigger (if you use virtualisation).  **2**  If  you have access to a profiler, look if you have bottlenecks or deadlock issues in your application code.  **3** Apache can be configured as a load balancer between both JBoss.  **4** Certain applications need to share sessions between instances, or you have to setup load balancing for server affinity.  **Final** this is a huge subject, outside of what is possible to express here on SO.

Comment: Thx for the detailed explanation. In case of deployment, can I do it once for both?

Comment: For deployment, you have to manage each JBoss instance as if they are standalones.  This allows you to have high availability (you can loose one without loosing your site), and you could update one, redirect traffic towards it while you update the other.